# JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS gradle problem while building Unity project App Bundle

Tags: unity-game-engine, build.gradle, android-app-bundle

I have a problem with the build gradle in Unity.

I was trying to build my Unity android project when it sended me the message that somthing when wrong and it gived me this message.

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\educp\Documents\Proyectos de unity\It's Complicated\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\launcher\build.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':launcher'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check'.
> Cannot parse project property android.enableR8='' of type 'class java.lang.String' as boolean. Expected 'true' or 'false'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

As far as I understand the problem is with a boolean in the build gradle file. I've already checked the SDK path and everything seems fine. Honestly, I don't have a clue what exactly is going on. Can someone help with this please?? Thanks in advance!!!